# Parsing MediaWiki generated content using Xpath in Python

Tags: python, html, css, xml, xpath

I'm trying to parse HTML that is generated by a MediaWiki page.

The structure looks like this:

```
<h3> some headline that relates to the information below </h3>
<ul><li>data i want</li>
<li>optional data i want</li></ul>
<h3> some other headline that relates to the info below</h3>
<ul><li>data</li></ul>
```

As you can see, the headings and the lists are on the same level in the html structure, which makes it a bit hard to parse. I'm using `scrapy` which provides a way of getting information based on `css` or `xpath` expressions. 
I've tried with some luck, but the problem is how to couple each heading `<h3>` with the corresponding `<ul>` In XPath, is there any way to read siblings of h3 until next h3 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Xpath expression I have tested on your HTML :

```
'//h3[1] | //h3[1]/following-sibling::ul[1]//li/text()'
```

feel free to iterate over the `h3` to replace all of the `1` by the *index* found instead of hard-coding it.